# how to get all messages of a bulit-in function in mma? i.e. all messages of Sin

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

how to get all messages of a bulit-in function in mma?

For example, I want to get all messages of Sin.

How to do this?

`Messages[Sin]` doesn't work.

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you mean generic messages like `::argx` as when you enter: `Sin[1, 2]`?

Comment: Thanks, Mr.Wizard. :) No, I want all messages. Maybe `NDSolve` is a better decription of my quesion. I wonder all messages of `NDSolve`: `NDSolve::nderr`, `NDSolve::eerr`, `NDSolve::mxsst`,...

Comment: In that case, WReach's answer should help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The messages for built-in functions are often not loaded until they have been issued at least once.  For such functions, you might try inspecting `Messages.m`:

```
NotebookOpen @
  FileNameJoin @
    { $InstallationDirectory
    ,"SystemFiles"
    ,"Kernel"
    ,"TextResources"
    ,"English"
    ,"Messages.m"
    }
```

or

```
FindList[
  FileNameJoin @
    { $InstallationDirectory
    ,"SystemFiles"
    ,"Kernel"
    ,"TextResources"
    ,"English"
    ,"Messages.m"
    }
, "NDSolve"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in messages like `::argx`, these are common to many functions.  You can view them with:

```
Messages[General]
```

You can view the usage message with:

```
Sin::usage
```